# Failing to connect to Atlas from C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

We have a test `Atlas` database up and running.

We can connect to it using `Mongo Shell` and list the collections from the database successfully.

However, when we try and connect using C# (running the following code):

```
var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("mongodb+srv://menadmin:<our password here>@cluster0.k2loi.mongodb.net/MAP?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
var dbList = client.ListDatabases().ToList();
```

Where  is replaced by our password. Running this code gives this error:

> System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a
> server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector
>
> { AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } ,
> OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is {
> ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet",
> State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "
>
> { ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00.k2loi.mongodb.net:27017" } ",
> EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00.k2loi.mongodb.net:27017",
> ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server.
> ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException
> (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
> not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond.
> 52.31.23.157:27017

We are using version 2.14.1 of the C# Mongo drivers. It also fails using version 2.10.4 with the same error. We have also tried the code from a .NET framework application and a .NET core application with the same result.

Do you have any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wirshark or fiddler and compare the working and non working connection.  There are too many reasons for this failure and without more info we would just be guessing.

Comment: check connection string (and connecting code) that atlas recommends you for c# application